# Reducing time for query

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to run the below query, but it is taking too long time because the data is huge:

```
SELECT pre.Count AS Precount, consol.Count AS commoncount, post.Count AS Postcount, Precount-commoncount AS deleted, postcount-commoncount AS added
FROM (SELECT COUNT([PRE_L]) AS [count] FROM PRE_LNADJL_2)  AS pre,
     (SELECT COUNT([PRE_L]) AS [count] FROM CD_LNADJL)  AS consol,
     (SELECT COUNT([Post_L]) AS [count] FROM POST_LNADJL_2)  AS post;
```

Comment: 1. Pls do not use uppercase characters throughout your post, it is considered shouting and is therefore rude. 2. Pls use appropriate tags for your question. It can't have anything to do with MySQL, since it uses different way to indicate aliases. Access tag is meant for security. 3. Since you are counting all records in 3 tables, there is very little room for optimisation.

Comment: What exactly do you want to count? All records? Then use `COUNT(*)`, it is much faster if the table has a primary key. Also try running the 3 subqueries separately, see how much faster this is.

Answer (score 0):

We used to do a little trick when I worked at an auditing firm where our back end was SQL Server and we were dealing with some tables with over 5B records.  What we would do was "pre-run" our reports.  That is to say, we would filter our data overnight and write it to new tables.  This way, all the larger, time-consuming calculations were done when no one needed the data.

I'd suggest you run an On Timer event set to run at a time when no one is in the office.  In that event, run something like:

```
INSERT INTO pre SELECT COUNT([PRE_L]) AS [count] FROM PRE_LNADJL_2
INSERT INTO consol SELECT COUNT([PRE_L]) AS [count] FROM CD_LNADJL
INSERT INTO post SELECT COUNT([Post_L]) AS [count] FROM POST_LNADJL_2
```

(You could also do SELECT INTO's, either one is fine depending on if you want to have to drop/recreate or clear your data holder tables every time this is run)

And then, whenever your user needs to run this report or whatever it is, the SQL only needs to be:

```
SELECT pre.Count AS Precount, consol.Count AS commoncount, post.Count AS Postcount, 
       Precount-commoncount AS deleted, postcount-commoncount AS added
FROM (SELECT * FROM pre),
 (SELECT * FROM consol),
 (SELECT * FROM post);
```

Should run in 2 seconds.